# Connect assets with handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, connect-assets

The typical way to include the connect assets file is

```
!= css("main")
```

That is with .jade though. I am using handlebars and I have no clue how I can add the file?

I am using `node-sass` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, something like this works (see [blog post](http://www.webuildinternet.com/2014/07/15/nodejs-asset-pipeline-with-handlebars/)):

```
var connectAssets = require("connect-assets")();
app.use(connectAssets);
var hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerHelper('css', function() {
  var css = connectAssets.options.helperContext.css.apply(this, arguments);
  return new hbs.SafeString(css);
});
```